# What's the proper way of declaring project constants in Java?

Tags: java, constants

This may seems a silly question for Java developers, however, I'm new to Java, and my background is from low level c.
I used to include an header file with all the constants that were relevant for my projects. (usually #define's).
I'm working on a big Java project now, and there a few constants I need to make global (they fit in more than one class, and used in various parts of the project )

It makes it hard for me to decide where to put it, should I declare the same constant few times, one in each class ?

A lot of framework, uses XML files to declare constants & definitions for the framework (Hibernate, Log4J, etc.) Is it wise to use this kind of technique in my project ? if so, how can it be done easily ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with many things, there are many ways to do it. One thing you should *not* do is declare them multiple times - that's just plain silly. :P

Everything has to be in a class in Java, so either:

1. Pick a "main" class (say I have a project called "FTPServerApp" - I could put them there)
2. Create a "Util" class that contains all of them

When you figure out where to put them, declare them all this way:

```
public static final [type] [NAME_IN_ALL_CAPS] = [value];
```

This will

- make them available to all your project code, anywhere (`public`)
- only one copy of the value exists across all instances of the class (`static`)
- they cannot be changed (`final`).

The `ALL_CAPS_FOR_CONSTANT_NAMES`, separated by underscores, is the convention in Java.

So, if this was declared in a class called `FTPServerAPP`, and you had a constant called `SERVICE_PORT` it might be:

```
public class FTPServerApp {
  public static final int SERVICE_PORT = 21;

  ...
}
```

...and you would access it, from any class, like this...

```
  FTPServerApp.SERVICE_PORT
```

Comment: I get it, but the concept is tedious, it's like object-orient programming is mis-used, members of a Class should represent the class itself, not export themselves as public constants. It works, but it smells fishy...

Comment: I agree. Nothing more to say than that. Because of the languages you come from, your perspective is tilted in that direction. Perfectly natural. I felt the same way the first time I created a utility class that had nothing but constants in it (i.e. no actual data, or functionality), but that is the way it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at enumeration types (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) They are supposed to provide a mechanism to supply constants without defining a concrete class (or an Interface with the desired constants, as is another option that people use).

One other technique I find helpful (similar to the FTPServerApp example given above) is to define a Context for whatever subsystem/component/etc... that holds not only the constants needed by components in that system, but can hold any state that you want to make more visible or don't want individual components to hold.  I believe this is along the lines of one of the GoF patterns, but it has been so long since I have looked at that book that I can't be certain (and I am too lazy to look it up right now!)

Answer (score 0):

Very old question. but here's my Ans adding few point on top of jefflunt's ans.
Lets consider you want a `MyConstant` class

1. Make the class `final` (if you want it to be extended, ignore)
2. Make member variables `final static`

   - if you want these as a global constants mark them as `public`
   - if only at package you can mark them as `protected`
3. Make constructor as `private`. Ideally you'd not want to create multiple instances of this Constant class
4. Write a `static` `initialize()` method that you'd call from your main class. This is for the initialization of all object member variables

```
public final class MyConstants {
    
    public static final int CONSTANT_ONE = 10;
    private static final Map<String, String> DATA = new HashMap<>();

    public static void initialize() {
        DATA.put("RANDOM", "VALUE");
    }
    public enum color {
        red, blue;
    };

    private MyConstants() {
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getData() {
        return DATA;
    }
}
```

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyConstants.initialize();
        System.out.println(MyConstants.getData());
        System.out.println(MyConstants.CONSTANT_ONE);
    }
}
```