# what is the proper way of declaring arrays in a class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, constants

what is the proper way of declaring constants array in a class? I have read post where ppl make a case for

```
public static final Strings[] words;
```

like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781037/whats-the-proper-way-of-declaring-project-constants-in-java)

however, I find that declaring your variables public, it means that the user(tester) can see the variables; even though, he can't change them because they are final... anyone could explain why should I declare the above constant instead of

```
private static final Strings[] words;
```

or just

```
private final Strings[] words;
```

thanks

Comment: What is the variable being USED for?

Answer (score 4):

Usually you shouldn't use arrays in Java, unless you really need the performance.

You should use a `Collection` (or a `List` if it's ordered) instead.

For a public constant,

`public static final Collection<String> FIXED_STRINGS = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList("string1","string2"));`

Or `private`, if it's not for use outside the class.

Comment: If you are going to make it unmodifiable, why bother with the Collection? At that point, you could have saved yourself the effort and JVM time and just gone with `public static final String[] STRINGS = {"string1", "string2"};`

Comment: @josh.trow Arrays can't be made immutable, so someone could do `STRINGS[1] = "badString"`

Answer (score 1):

The example you point to talks about public `String` constants, not public `String[]`.

You can't make `String[]` unchangeable.  `final` only means a user can't make the reference point to a different object.  It does not prevent the user from changing the contents of the array.  (`final` in Java is very different (and less powerful) than `const` in C++).

As for whether or not `static` should be there, remember what the difference is.  With the `static`, the member will be shared by all instances of the class.  Without the `static` there will be a separate copy of the member in every instance of the class.

Generally when something is a true constant that is wasteful and so in such situations `static` is generally used.

Answer (score 0):

it's just depends what you want to do, like any object oriented concept.

public/private/... is the access you want to declare to your members/method.

BTW final indicate that you cannot change the variable once initialized.
static means that all the instance of the class will have the same variable.

In short all is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using enums to declare constants:

```
public enum Words {

    ONE("one"),
    TWO("two");

    private String title;

    private Words(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Which is very convenient to use (Words.ONE) and you can associate other attributes with each property (title, etc).

You can also get the array of constants by calling Words.values();

Comment: this has nothing to do with declaring arrays

Comment: Yes it does.  You can call .values() on the enum to get the array of all enum values.

Answer (score 0):

declaring a class variable public is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class variables.

it also opens your class to other people writing code that will be dependent on that specific class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the static or final keyword does, as it does not show in your question!

Read about static & final first!

> It should be **static final** as then only it'll actually hold some
>   meaning for being a constant!

Btw, "Strings"??

Answer (score 0):

Since **String [] words** is final you can initialize it once I.e if you say string [] words=new string[5]
Or you initialized it any other way but once its initialized you can't make it to refer some other instance of string array.
but its element can be changed.
example words[0]="string1" can be changed to words[0]="string2"
If you say
 private static final string[] words then words will become class variable and can be access within class.
if you say 
 private final string [] words then words will become instance variable and can be accessed within class
if you say variable as public then it can be accessed out side class and its element can be modified by any one.

**Recommendation**
1.Use **enum**
2. Use list and make it unmodifiable using Collections.unmodifiableList()